# How should I write this rule in CLIPS?

Tags: clips

Please, help me create the rules in CLIPS to resolve this tasks:

1. The goalkeeper has to move on the goal post line in that position where it can block the trajectory of the ball.
2. The defenders have to move so that to block the ball in its trajectory towards goal or to block the trajectory of an opponent player that moves towards the goal post that must be defended.

```
(deftemplate temp
(players <number_robots>)
(Goal_posts <number_goal_posts>)
(Field <dimension>)
(players goalkeeper <number_goalkeepers> <goalkeeper_linear_speed> <goalkeeper_angular_speed> {static, running})
(players defenders <number_defenders> <defender_linear_speed> <defender_angular_speed> {static, running})
(players midfielder <number_midfielders> <midfielder_linear_speed> <midfielder_angular_speed> {static, running})
(players striker <number_strikers> <striker_linear_speed> <striker_angular_speed> {static, running})
(ball <poz_x> <poz_y)
(oponents <nume> <poz_oponents_x> <poz_oponents_y>))

(deffacts initial-state
    (player goalkeeper 1 10 6 static)
    (player defenders number_defenders 15 10 running)
    (player midfielders number_midfielders 17 12 running)
    (player strikers number_strikers 9 10 running)
    (ball 5 5)
    (oponents Robot1 1 2)
    (oponents Robot2 2 4)
    (oponents Robot3 7 2)
    (oponents Robot4 10 20)
    (oponents Robot5 11 8)
    (oponents Robot6 20 10)
    (oponents Robot7 5 9)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create a pseudo rule to implement:

```
If the player position slot is goalkeeper and
   the player x slot is not the same as the ball x slot
Then
   modify the player x slot to the value of the ball x slot
```

Next, define the data structures needed to retrieve the slot values referenced by your pseudo rule:

```
         CLIPS (6.4 2/9/21)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate ball
   (slot x)
   (slot y))
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate player
   (slot position)
   (slot x)
   (slot y))
CLIPS>
```

Then convert your pseudo rule to CLIPS syntax:

```
CLIPS>    
(defrule move-goalkeeper
   ?p <- (player (position goalkeeper)
                 (x ?px))
   (ball (x ?bx&~?px))
   =>
   (modify ?p (x ?bx)))
CLIPS>
```

Finally, test the rule to see that it works:

```
CLIPS> (assert (ball (x 3) (y 5)))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (assert (player (position goalkeeper) (x 4) (y 3)))
<Fact-2>
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      move-goalkeeper: f-2,f-1
For a total of 1 activation.
CLIPS> (run)
CLIPS> (facts)
f-1     (ball (x 3) (y 5))
f-2     (player (position goalkeeper) (x 3) (y 3))
For a total of 2 facts.
CLIPS>
```